# How to align setError when fitSystemWindows is true

Tags: android

I'm using translucent toolbars in my app and have applied the following settings:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

This works as expected, however when I display any error messages on my EditTexts via setError, the error message is not aligned properly. For example, here is an error message when fitsSystemWindows is true:

[image]

Here is an error message when fitsSystemWindows is false:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get the alignment correct when fitsSystemWindows=true?

Comment: Fixed thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741824/simple-android-toasts-not-aligning-properly