# Toast text not fit (overflow)

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I got problem with my toasts, as you can see [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZDLw.png) text is not fitting. Have you got any idea why there is this issue? 
On Android 5.0 toasts looks normal but in 4.3 not.

My style.xml

```
<style name="_SelectorParent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>

<style name="_mainParent" parent="@style/_SelectorParent">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here on stack, you must change `android:fitsSystemWindows` to `false`. Explained here: [Simple Android toasts not aligning properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741824/simple-android-toasts-not-aligning-properly)